# How to get data from one Exe to another Exe using Nodejs Child_process

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I have two exe files(Intro.exe and Main.exe) created using Node-webkit.  I have one variable(sendData) in Intro.exe. I want to send **sendData** variable from Intro.exe to Main.exe .  I used The following code in Intro.exe for executing Main.exe

```
    var sendData = "sending Data";
    var path = require("path");
    var sPath = path.dirname(process.execPath);

    var exec = require('child_process').execFile, childWin;
    childWin = exec(Main.exe,[sendData], {cwd:sPath}, function(err, data) {
             Console.log(data);
    });
```

Now, I want to get **sendData** in Main.exe . 
what code I want to use in Main.exe for getting data. Thanks in advance